# Generating dynamically Schema LD+JSON microdata with Javascript works in test environment but not in WP

Tags: javascript

I am writing with `js` a product review grid. I provide some values as `js` variables, the script basically draws progress bars and takes the average of the values, as in this image below.

[image: Microdata in local environment]

I then want to use the name of the product and the average rating as [Schema](https://schema.org/) microdata.

I have the (simplified) following code, that locally works fine (see again attached image). The idea to dynamically generate `ld-json` from `js` is taken [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58698112/insert-variable-from-jquery-into-json-schema-markup).

**index.html**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src='review-grid.js'> </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <script>
        var product_name = "Algida Magnum";
        var img_url = "https://../img.jpg";
        var properties = [ "Taste", "Price"];
        var votes = [5, 6];

        // Schema construction
        makeReviewGrid(product_name, img_url, votes);
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**review-grid.js**

```js
function makeReviewGrid(product_name, img_url, votes) {

    // ... build review grid

    // Schema markup
    var schema = 
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "Product",
      "brand": {
        "@type": "Brand",
        "name": brand_name
      },
      "image": img_url,
      "name": product_name,
      "review": {
          "@type": "Review",
          "author": {
           ...
            },
          "reviewRating": {
            "@type": "Rating",
            "ratingValue": average_vote,
            "bestRating": "10",
            "worstRating": "1"
          }
      }
    }
    
    // Dynamically generate ld-json from js
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = "application/ld+json";
    script.text = JSON.stringify(schema);
    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(script);
}
```

`review-grid.js` is hooked in child theme `functions.php` with

```php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );

function add_my_script() {
    if(is_singular() && in_category('Recensioni')) {
        wp_register_script(
            'review_grid_js', 
            get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/review-grid.js', 
            array('jquery') 
        );

        wp_enqueue_script('review_grid_js');
    }
}
```

### Problem

Again, locally the code works fine: the review grid appears and the microdata is all there.

But when I test this in Wordpress, the review grid works fine **but no microdata appears**.

**But** if I put the part of `review-grid.js` generating the schema microdata directly in the `<script>` tag in `index.html` rather then in the external function `makeReviewGrid`, then it works fine in Wordpress.

Any idea where the problem can be?

[image: No microdata in live page]

Comment: In the server-generated page source, does it have `review-grid.js`, i.e. is the script actually loaded and that it's loaded before you call the `makeReviewGrid()` function? And note that your script is adding the metadata in the body and not head, so have you checked in the body? Also, your actual (WordPress) template does call `wp_head()`, right?

Comment: Hey @SallyCJ, thanks for the comment! yes to all your answers; I kept trying and now it works,  not sure where the flaw was

Comment: It's probably just a caching issue.. but anyway, glad to hear it now works :)